# MPAndroidChart how to listen to PieChart rotation?

Tags: android, pie-chart, mpandroidchart

I'm using [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) (A wonderfull chart library BTW), to set-up a Pie Chart [like in the example given](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartExample/src/com/xxmassdeveloper/mpchartexample/PieChartActivity.java). The generated pie chart can be manually turned to perform rotations over his center. I am currently trying to listen to the rotation event and was wondering if there was a way of doing so using the library.
I've unsuccessfully tried to use the following listener for that :

```
onDrawListener 
setOnClickListener 
setOnLongClickListener
addOnLayoutChangeListener
```

Thanks,

Comment: Did you find a solution? I would like to have a rotation-listener as well. It would be great if it tells me how much it was rotated or the angle after it stopped rotating.

Comment: No we didn't implement this functionality at the end. Sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to read the current rotation angle. I run this command in a while(true) loop inside a coroutine with a delay of 10 ms.

```
GlobalScope.launch {
        while (true) {
            try {
                val rotation = pieChart.rotationAngle
                delay(10)
            } catch (ex: Exception) {
                // do nothing
            }
        }
    }
```

It is an Easter Egg in my App and if a user spins the PieChart 10 times in 3 seconds I show something funny.

To check if the user did a full rotation I set checkpoints along the rotation and see if the user passed them. After 3 seconds all checkpoints will be reset.

```
if (rotating && rotation < 100 && checkpoints == 0) {
        fullRotations += 1
        checkpoints = 1
    } else if (rotating && rotation > 100 && rotation < 200 && checkpoints == 1) {
        checkpoints = 2
    } else if (rotating && rotation > 200 && rotation < 360 && checkpoints == 2) {
        checkpoints = 3
    } else if (rotating && rotation < 100 && checkpoints == 3) {
        fullRotations += 1
        checkpoints = 1
    }
```

One could use this code to create events out of it like -> do something if 'n' full rotations happened. As soon as you keep track of the change in rotation angle you can do what you want. If you have your event you could create a ListenerInterface and implement it in your class. Then you have your callback.

The while(true) maybe isn't the most elegant way but in my case it works pretty well. Tell me if you want my code. I didn't want to overload my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How do you create the `rotating` variable ?

Comment: the creation is in the upper code snippet -> val rotation = pieChart.rotationAngle

Comment: @IsmailH you asked for a different variable 'rotating'. In my case I just check if the rotation value is larger than 300 degrees and was not rotating before. As 300 degrees are close to one full rotation it fits in my case to tell that there is a rotation going on. I also take the time of this event to reset the easter egg after a couple of seconds ##Code### if (rotation > 300f && !rotating) {
            canceled = false
            rotating = true
            lastRotationAngle = rotation
            timeRotationStart = System.currentTimeMillis()
        }

Answer (score 2):

**Currently that is not possible**. You would have to write your own listener and modify the classes of the library responsible for processing touch events.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something a little more efficient. You can use the chart's `OnTouch` listener to listen for `ACTION_MOVE` events, which correspond to a user dragging the chart:

```
chart.setOnTouchListener { v, event ->
            when (event.action) {
                MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {
                    // Here's the rotation
                    val rot = chart.rotationAngle
                }
            }
            false
        }
```

That way, whenever the user moves the chart, you get its rotation.